# How to get `comint` modes work with long lines?

Tags: comint, inferior-python-mode

When I paste a long (not that long) line in `inferior-python-mode`, the buffer sucks. For example,

```
"[{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"contract I_StarkwareContract\",\"name\":\"starkwareContractAddress\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"contract IERC20\",\"name\":\"usdcAddress\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"usdcAssetType\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"trustedForwarder\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"constructor\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"sender\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":false,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"tokenFrom\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":false,\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"tokenFromAmount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"indexed\":false,\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"usdcAmount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"LogConvertedDeposit\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"previousOwner\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"newOwner\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"OwnershipTransferred\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":false,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"account\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"Paused\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":false,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"account\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"Unpaused\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"STARKWARE_CONTRACT\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"contract I_StarkwareContract\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"depositAmount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"starkKey\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"positionId\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"bytes\",\"name\":\"signature\",\"type\":\"bytes\"}],\"name\":\"deposit\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"contract IERC20\",\"name\":\"tokenFrom\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"tokenFromAmount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"starkKey\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"positionId\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"contract I_ExchangeProxy\",\"name\":\"exchangeProxy\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"bytes\",\"name\":\"exchangeProxyData\",\"type\":\"bytes\"},{\"internalType\":\"bytes\",\"name\":\"signature\",\"type\":\"bytes\"}],\"name\":\"depositERC20\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"starkKey\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"positionId\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"contract I_ExchangeProxy\",\"name\":\"exchangeProxy\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"bytes\",\"name\":\"exchangeProxyData\",\"type\":\"bytes\"},{\"internalType\":\"bytes\",\"name\":\"signature\",\"type\":\"bytes\"}],\"name\":\"depositEth\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"payable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"forwarder\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"isTrustedForwarder\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"bool\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"owner\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"pause\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"paused\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"bool\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"renounceOwnership\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"newOwner\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"transferOwnership\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"unpause\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"}]"
```

I type `s =`  and paste and press enter, the buffer becomes no longer usable unless I do a `ctrl-c`.

I tested in an `emacs -q` session with the command `run-python`.

Emacs version: `GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin22.3.0, Carbon Version 169 AppKit 2299.4) of 2023-08-09`

[image]

Comment: Your example works perfectly fine here (emacs version: `GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.38, cairo version 1.17.8) of 2023-08-09`)

Comment: @dalanicolai Then it looks like an issue of `emacs-mac`.

Comment: I have tried with a Mac now, and indeed I can confirm the described behavior there.

Comment: @dalanicolai Do you use `emacs-plus` or `emacs-mac` or other ports? I'm using `emacs-mac`: `GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin22.3.0, Carbon Version 169 AppKit 2299.4) of 2023-08-09`

Comment: I have simply installed the Emacs binary for Mac: `GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 1, aarch64-apple-darwin21.6.0, NS appkit-2113.60 Version 12.6.6 (Build 21G646)) of 2023-08-17`

Comment: I'm on the latest emacs-plus@30 for mac and this happens on all comint-based shells for me.